# how to resolve the canvas not supported error

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am using HTML5 Canvas,javascript. I have made an page with the help of html5 canvas and javascript..But when I run it it gave me this error

> ("Error=Unable to get the value of the property 'getContext': object
>   is null or undefined")

but it does not terminate the program..the program is running fine with this .

```
 function draw(canvas0) {
     var canvas = canvas0;
     options = null;

     // Canvas good?
     if (canvas !== null && canvas.getContext)

 }


 function initCanvas() {
     var canvas1 = document.getElementById('tutorial');
     var canvas2 = document.getElementById('tutorial1');
     var canvas3 = document.getElementById('tutorial2');
     var canvas4 = document.getElementById('tutorial3');
     var canvas5 = document.getElementById('tutorial4');

     draw(canvas1);
     draw(canvas2);
     draw(canvas3);
     draw(canvas4);
     draw(canvas5);
 }
```

this is where i am getting the id and returning these values

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Speedometer HTML5 Canvas</title>
    <script src="script copy.js">

    </script>

</head>
<body onload='initCanvas();'>

        <canvas id="tutorial" width="440" height="220" style="zoom:50%">
            Canvas not available.
        </canvas>
        <canvas id="tutorial1" width="440" height="220" style="zoom:50%">
            Canvas not available.
        </canvas>
        <canvas id="tutorial2" width="440" height="220" style="zoom:50%">
            Canvas not available.
        </canvas>
        <canvas id="tutorial3" width="440" height="220" style="zoom:50%">
            Canvas not available.
        </canvas>
        <canvas id="tutorial4" width="440" height="220" style="zoom:50%">
            Canvas not available.
        </canvas>

        <form id="drawTemp">

        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

after seeing the answer given by [kennebec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429225/javascript-null-or-undefined#comment14094488_6429443) if have created change in my code

`if (canvas != null && canvas.getContext)`.

After using this line the getContext error is not coming ,But after executing the page that is after drawing the canvas it gives me new error ("Canvas Not Supported By Your Browser").Help me out here.

Comment: What is `canvas0`? Shouldn't you be using something like `var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas0')`?

Comment: What does `document.getElementById('tutorial')` return?

Comment: Hi, I ran your code in chrome without any modification. It does not give me the error and its working fine.

Comment: no when i am adding this page to tableau it gave me this error ..i have searched some thing but i dont know what does it suppose to mean      [please go through this page and read the answer by GAgnew](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679355/canvas-animation-javascript-functions-and-global-variables)

Comment: I assume this happens in older IE where Canvas is not supported. Have you considered https://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/ ?

Comment: if (canvas !== null && canvas.getContext) 
when i am using this line it run successfully(by successfully i mean , it gives me error of getContex but it run anyway) but when i use 
  if (canvas != null && canvas.getContext).then it gives me that error

Comment: and yes i have already considered it but this does not do the magic for me

Comment: What browser and version are you using when you get the error `Canvas Not Supported By Your Browser` ? The following has a matrix for browwser support of CANVAS: http://guides.instructure.com/s/2204/m/4214/l/41056-which-browsers-does-canvas-support

Comment: You said _`when i am adding this page to tableau it gave me this error`_ What is `tableau`?

Comment: i am using IE10 ..And Tableau is a tool for representing the data. [tableau](http://www.tableausoftware.com/business-intelligence).

Comment: It works perfectly for me http://cssdeck.com/labs/t1qtwjei I simply added brackets after the if statement and took out the unnecessary script tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had checked this , I didn't get , why are you facing this problem,though i don't know about tableau much

```
   canvas != null && canvas.getContext
```

by this you are getting another error  "Canvas not supported by your  browser
when i am dong this this error comes after the canvas is drawn. then i just delete that alert which gave me this alert message.i think you must try this ,search for this alert and see what happen next  it does not effect the program and it runs fine